# Images are not displayed (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I transferred my local application to my server. But the images on my server are not displayed even if I type the url manually in my browser.

Good to remember that in my local application, everything works correctly.

My system is working properly on the server too, but the images are not being displayed. (Everything ok with javascript and css).

What could be the problem?

Comment: when you manually type the url are you adding /app/webroot/img/ or just /img ?

Comment: Can you review the server error and/or access logs? Or, check the developer console (F12 in most browsers) to see if the image requests are returning HTTP errors?

Comment: Amstegraf -> just /img

Comment: Justin -> I already solved the problem, sorry for waste your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem, sorry for inconvenience.

It was a case sensitive image name problem. Since my local server is running on windows and my server is running on linux. Windows ignores case , Linux not.

My question still here to save time of people who are having the same problem.